# Copy/paste validation on input field and restrict character

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on validation of an input control when the user copy paste some value in it

On pasting to this input I want to strip out as below:

- Input can start with underscore or an alphabet
- Input cannot start with number
- Input cannot have any spl character except underscore
- Input cannot have spaces

This is allowed:

```
abc
abc_123
_123bcd
_123_bcd
```

This is not:

```
123abc
123_acd
abc s22
```

I tried with the below code:

```
@HostListener('paste', ['$event']) blockPaste(event: KeyboardEvent) {
      this.stripInput(event);
  }

  stripInput(event) {    
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.el.nativeElement.value = this.el.nativeElement.value.replace(/[^A-Za-z ]+/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '');
          event.preventDefault();
      }, 100);
  }
```

But with above code its not fully working, it doesnt allows:
abc_123
_123_ams

Any inputs please

Comment: This really isn't a JavaScript question. It's just a regular expression question.

Comment: So if `123_acd` is pasted then you wish to convert it to `_acd` or do you wish to tell the user to fix it? Validation is a totally different subject than input masking.

Comment: 123_acd should strip to _acd thats why I am adding prevent default

Comment: Use a library such as https://imask.js.org/. There's really no reason to roll out your own solution. See this section https://imask.js.org/guide.html#pattern

Comment: Do note that changing the user's input as they type is a very jarring experience. It would be much more user friendly if you allowed them to type freely and presented an error message when their input does not match the regex.

Comment: Try: `^[^\W\d]\w+$`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus user is aware of what to type as I have help text its just during copy paste i want to make sure I strip out

Comment: @ctwheels that is not working. I have my code hre: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ovqvop

Answer (score 0):

You have made a simple over sight with regards to your initial regex. You did not add a start of string check (which is needed to remove numbers and extra special characters at the start of the string). You will also need another query if you want to remove other special characters from within the string as well

if you change your last block of code to -

```
@HostListener('paste', ['$event']) blockPaste(event: KeyboardEvent) {
      this.stripInput(event);
  }

  stripInput(event) {    
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.el.nativeElement.value = this.el.nativeElement.value.replace(/^[^A-Za-z_]+/g, '').replace(/[^0-9A-Za-z_]+/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '');
          event.preventDefault();
      }, 100);
  }
```

It should work as expected (Note the extra `^` at the start of the regex and the added `_` to your initial regex as well as the extra following regex).

What this does pin the search to the start of the string instead of allowing it to act on all parts of the string. It works on your `abc_123 _123_ams` input and it also strips the extra space in the middle of it as intended. (it makes it `abc_123_123_ams`)